# The sum of two numbers is 5/9....

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The sum of two numbers is $\frac{5}{9}$. The quotient of the two numbers is $1$. What is the product of $40$% of each number?

The answer I got was $\frac{1}{81}$. 
I don't understand this - would someone mind explaining it to me? 
Thanks a ton for your time!

I have tried:

$x+y=\frac{5}{9}$

$\frac{x}{y} = 1$

But then I don't know what to do after this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. You have
$$
x+x=\frac59
$$ (why?)

Now you are asked to evaluate $(0.40 \times x) \times (0.40 \times y)=\frac25 \times \frac25 \times x^2$ (why?).

Comment: I read the last instruction as asking for $(0.4 x)\cdot (0.4y)$

Comment: Oops! Thanks @Hagen von Eitzen!

Comment: @ArchisWelankar From $x/y=1$ you get $y=x$...

Comment: Thanks for the help, @OlivierOloa!

Comment: @Carlos Carlsen You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**$$\begin{cases}
x+y=\frac59
\\
\frac{x}{y}=1 
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
x+y=\frac59
\\
x=y
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
x=...
\\
y=...
\end{cases}$$
$N=0.4x\cdot 0.4y=...$

Comment: I see - so, if $x=y$, then $\frac{5}{9}$$/2$ = $\frac{5}{18}$

Comment: $2x=\frac 59 \Rightarrow x=\frac{5}{18}$

Comment: Right, which, when divided by itself, the answer is equal to $1$. Now, it is just a matter of solving $N$. Thanks a ton!